# Corona sdk Get Sim Card Details

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm creating an Application using Corona sdk with Lua Language, can anyone help me with getting Sim Card details such as, mobile Number, pin no .. etc

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corona provides `system.getInfo()` for getting device-specific information. I dont think you can find the mobile Number, but there is some info you can get.

You can get more details in the [docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/getInfo.html)

You probably will find `deviceID` useful:

> On iOS, "deviceID" returns a "unique" id for the device. Per Apple's policies, on iOS 6 and later, "deviceID" returns a MD5 hash of the device's "identifierForVendor" (see below); on iOS 5 it returns a MD5 of a GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) that is unique for each app install.
>
> On Android, if your app uses the "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" permission, the following will be returned:
>
> - IMEI for GSM phones.
> - MEID or ESN for CDMA phones.
> - The operating system's unique ID for devices that are not phones.
>
> If your Android app does not use the "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" permission, then the operating system's unique ID will be returned for all devices. Note that the operating system's unique ID may change after re-installing the operating system on the device.